# How to reference files in .dart_tools in a flutter project?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying out [inject.dart](https://github.com/google/inject.dart) in my side project, but have been unsuccessful in getting my app to compile.

If it helps, you can see my project [here](https://github.com/grandstaish/monzo-flutter/).

I've copied the `inject` and `inject_generator` packages into my project since there's currently no official release. Then, I run:

`pub run build_runner build` (or `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`)

I see the generated files all being created in `.dart_tools/build/generated` successfully, however my files in `lib/` can't reference the generated files. Hence I just get a compilation error every time I try to run my app.

Has anyone got any clues as to what I am (or might be) doing wrong? Am I even supposed to be able to reference files in this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get the desired result by specifying `build_to: source` like shown in this example

https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/10667edc1ed4f3e5d15fcfd2d0a447113f89e982/example/build.yaml

```
builders:

  copyBuilder:
    import: "package:example/builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["copyBuilder"]
    build_extensions: {".txt": [".txt.copy"]}
    build_to: source
    auto_apply: root_package
```

There is some explanation in https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/dff811be8b99e0ac7b15a8c7b9ad7bd2b5027a1d/build_config/README.md

> - *build_to*: Optional. The location that generated assets should be
>     output to. The possibilities are: `"source"`: Outputs go to the source
>     tree next to their primary inputs. `"cache"`: Outputs go to a hidden
>     build cache and won't be published. The default is "cache". If a
>     Builder specifies that it outputs to "source" it will never run on any
>     package other than the root - but does not necessarily need to use the
>     "root_package" value for "auto_apply". If it would otherwise run on a
>     non-root package it will be filtered out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it after work. If a library specifies `build_to` in its `build.yaml`, can you override it as a consumer of that library? Or are you suggesting I just modify my copied version of inject.dart?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I assume this is how it works (override package defaults).

Comment: For future readers, more discussion can be found at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16603